# How to make all the modules as one file when using yum to install?

Tags: centos, yum

I have multiple nodes and I am trying to install some libraries through yum.
But the problem is that most of the nodes aren't not connected to the external-Internet. (Nodes can reach other nodes through the Intranet, which means that interconnections between nodes is fine)

So I cannot use yum in order to download the modules I want.

So I could add a new network card to each node and give it another ip address. But since I have more than 20 nodes this would be very labor-intensive.

So I want to avoid this as a solution and I maybe try:

When I use yum on the specific node that is able to connect to the Internet, I think there might exist unix-commands that could package all the dependent modules as one compressed file so that I could send to another node.

I tried to google for a solution, but failed to find an appropriate answer. Any help will be appreciated.

I am using CentOS 6.8.